# Service / Repository pattern for multiple integrations / backends?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have a domain entity named `Stream`. `Stream` has the following model:

```js
export type StreamConnectorType = 'TYPE1' | 'TYPE2';

export type StreamType1Details = {
  // Properties relates to Type1
}

export type StreamType1Details = {
  // Properties relates to Type2
}

export type StreamConnector = {
  type: StreamConnectorType;
  details: StreamType1Details | StreamType1Details;
}

export type Stream = {
  id: string;
  authorId: string;
  connector: StreamConnector;
  externalId?: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  status: string;
};
```

Depending on the `connector.type`, a different backend will be used. For example, `TYPE1` backend may involve setting up a "Stream" of data using Kafka. `TYPE2` backend may be a "Stream" of data using AWS Stepfunctions. Other types will additionally be supported in the future.

A "Stream" will be stored in a database with the `externalId` pointed to the id of whatever backend type. For Kafka, a UUID. For Stepfunctions, an arn.

Following the `Service` / `Repository` pattern, I had this to begin with:

```js
export interface IStreamRepository {
  getById(id: string): Promise<Stream>;
  create(f: StreamCreateParams): Promise<Pick<Stream, 'id'>;
  update(id: string, update: StreamUpdateParams): Promise<void>;
  delete(id: string): Promise<void>;
  listByAuthorId(authorId: string): Promise<Stream[]>;
}

export interface IStreamService {
  getById(id: string): Promise<Stream>;
  create(f: StreamCreateParams): Promise<Pick<Stream, 'id'>;
  update(id: string, update: StreamUpdateParams): Promise<void>;
  delete(id: string): Promise<void>;
  listByAuthorId(authorId: string): Promise<Stream[]>;
}
```

with an implementation of the IStreamRepository for all the different types of backends:

- `AwsStepFunction implements IStreamRepository`
- `Kafka implements IStreamRepository`
- `Database implements IStreamRepository`

This worked fine, but the `Database` requires an `externalId` while the other types didn't. And the other types had a `status` while the `Database` didn't. This isn't represented at the `IStreamRepository` layer, so I decided to break it up between two repositories / domain types:

```js
export interface IStreamRepository {
  // Same functions again
}

export type StreamExternal = Omit<Stream, 'externalId'> & { status: string };
export interface IStreamExternalRepository {
  // Same functions except with StreamExternal type
}
```

Now, it's:

- `AwsStepFunctionExternalStreamRepository implements IStreamExternalRepository`
- `KafkaExternalStreamRepository implements IStreamExternalRepository`
- `Database implements IStreamRepository`

Additionally, my service layer has a factory that pulls the external repository *per* type:

```js
class StreamExternalRepositoryFactory {
  static getRepository(type: StreamConnectorType): StreamExternalRepository {
    if(type === 'KAFKA') {
      return new KafkaExternalStreamRepository();
    } else if (type === 'AWS_STEPFUNCTION') {
      return new AwsStepFunctionExternalStreamRepository(); 
    }
  }

}

class StreamService {
  constructor(private repositoryFactory: StreamExternalRepositoryFactory, private repository: IStreamRepository) {}

  getStream(id: string) {
    // Call database repo
    const stream = this.repository.findById(id);
    // Then call external repo for other details: `status`.
    const externalStream = this.repositoryFactory.getRepository(stream.connector.type).findById(id);
    return { ...stream, status: externalStream.status };
  }

  updateStream(id: string, update: StreamUpdateParams) {
    // Call database repo to get external id
    const stream = this.repository.findById(id);
    // Update external repo
    this.repositoryFactory.getRepository(stream.connector.type).update(id, update);
    // Persist in datastore changes
    this.repository.update(id, update);
  }
}
```

The only hang-up with this paradigm is that I have to assert that the types are valid at the repository level for each of the `types`. Other than that, it's no biggie.

Am I over complicating this or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I would give this a read - https://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer